# Absolute path of java gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a problem setting gradle project with absolute paths of already existing java projects.
So, I have a new gradle project admin-tool, but somewhere on my file-system I have existing java eclipse projects say ejb-services, dao-services (which are not gradle projects) so I want to integrate them in my new gradle project.
Is there any solution, that will give me freedom ejb-services and dao-services projects to be on any file-system location and integrate them in my new gradle project.
I have try with

```
project("dao-services").path = new File(/*absolute path*/)
include "dao-services","admin-tool"
```

also

```
 project("dao-services").projectDir = new File(/* absolute path */)
 include "dao-services","admin-tool"
```

But they all give me error that project dao-services could not be found.
From what I have search it's seems to me that gradle only uses relative paths to root project and you can't go out that scope, but I haven't found any information regarding this to be sure.
Best Regard and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot about the ':' in the module name, as in the

```
project(":dao-services")
```

Comment: Any way it give the same error, I have try a lot of variations

Comment: Include it first, and then modify `path` (and `buildFileName`, if needed) property.

Comment: I tried with absolute path on windows, and it didnt work (because path contains :), you have to use relative path for include (for example by java.nio.Path and its method relative())